# Log to Aptana console when debugging JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, aptana

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 to debug JavaScript code. It is a simple HTML page which is displayed in Internet Explorer.

I want to write log messages to the Aptana Console view. I have tried to use the following log function:

```
function log(message) {
    setTimeout(function() { throw new Error(message);}, 0);
}
```

This works, but when debugging the page, Aptana stops because of the `throw`. I have two questions:

1. Is there a built-in function to write log messages to the console?
2. If not, is there a way to tell the Aptana debugger to ignore the specific `throw` in my `log` function above?

Solutions should work in IE8 and above. Switching to another browser is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Developer Tools (F12) of IE 8 and above bring logging support to the Internet Explorer. This feature is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625%28VS.85%29.aspx#consolelogging). Simple logging is possible with:

```
console.log('my message');
```

Note that the `console` feature is not available until you start the developer tools.

However, this will display nothing within Aptana, but with the IE console you are able to see log messages.